# jquery fade images and menu drop down

Tags: jquery, css

I have a small problem when im working with a menu and a list of images that change with jquery, my problem is that when I'm on the menu the submenu that is lost in the list of images.

Comment: @Ron If you have new questions, post them as new questions by click the "Ask a Question" button at the top of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a higher `z-index` to your dropdown menu.

```
ul#nav { position:relative; z-index:100 }
```

This sets it up higher in the stack than the images that are fading in/out. As it is now, the moment you mouse-into an area containing an image, the focus is lost and the dropdown is closed (because you're moving onto an image, and off of the dropdown).

Comment: @henchman: Yes, but if I had said `ul#nav { z-index:100 }` others would have dealt harshly with me for the bad CSS :) Also, an upvote would be appreciated if you truly do agree with the answer ;) Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

> Change the image properties .

You need to add the css file.

position:fixed; or position:absolute ;

It may solve this problem.